# Why (else) would my Calendar icon have a red badge (with numbers) on it?

Tags: calendar, dock, ical

Supposedly, [the red badge that shows up on the Calendar icon in the app switcher (and the Dock, if anyone still uses that) represents invitations that you've not dealt with](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4676629?start=0&tstart=0).  That's a nice theory, but I have no invitations waiting for me to act on, and I still have a red badge with a "3" in it.

I realize that I can [disable the badge](http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/29/disable-red-badge-app-icons-mac-os-x/), but that seems like taking a hammer and smashing the light on the dashboard, instead of figuring out why it is lit up.

I want to know what (other than invitations waiting) could cause a red badge to show up on the Calendar.app icon.  If this is a bug (e.g. where Calendar is failing update its count of invitations) is there any way to fix it?  Is there any way to reset it?  If it's not a bug, what other entities get counted besides invitations?

Comment: Do you have any events with reminders setup? Does the Calendar app have any entries in Notification Center? Also, in my experience, badges are prone to weird bugs; you could try force-closing the app and restarting it or rebooting your phone.

Comment: It also shows if another party added or changed an event on a shared Calendar. However, if there is nothing showing in the Calendar's top bar concerning that, then my guess is it's a ghost. Try killing the Dock & see if it goes away. In terminal `killall -KILL Dock`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, disabled and reenabled the icloud account in calendar preferences and it got rid of the phantom badge

Answer (score 2):

I had to clear the notifications explicitly despite accepting a meeting invite. Here's a screenshot from macOS Mojave -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution was eventually just to ditch Apple Calendar (after death by a thousand paper cuts) and buy BusyCal.

No, I'm not affiliated with the company.  It's a bit overpriced in my opinion, but it's the best available option, and a calendar is pretty essential when you need one.  Even a lot of the features that I initially thought were silly have turned out to be very useful.  And they are *constantly* adding features, making tweaks, and fixing bugs.  Unlike Apple, in the case of their calendar.